# RepaintBoundary lifetime in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in RepaintBoundary class which is using to cache a layer in flutter.
the question is it will be stored on the cache memory or will be stored in a compile time,Only?

Comment: what "cache memory" do you mean?

Comment: i meant if i close the application the RepaintBoundary will not be destroyed, still be in the cache memory

Answer (score 0):

If you store anything in the cache memory, eventually it's bound to be deleted. It's not a good practice to rely on something being available in the cache memory all the time.